# Visual Studio blocks on deploying a Standalone Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022, which is 17.2.6.

If I create a new project of the type **"Standalond Typescript Angular Project"**,
make no modifications whatsoever and try to start the project, then it opens a
console window with title **ngcc** and (after a while) shows the following content:

```
> angularproject1@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |      Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   1.67 MB
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 336.18 kB
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 212.40 kB
main.js               | main          |  53.50 kB
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.87 kB

                      | Initial Total |   2.26 MB

Build at: 2022-07-16T15:17:53.888Z - Hash: ad802c438fec0f97 - Time: 12103ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
```

At this point I can open the address http://localhost:4200/ in a browser and it loads the page correctly.

However, Visual Studio gets stuck showing the text "Deploy started..." in the status bar.

The Visual Studio output window has the following content:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: angularproject1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Deploy started: Project: angularproject1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

If I abort the program in the console, the Visual Studio shows the message

```
There were deployment errors. Continue?
```

In another scenario, I have created a solution with two new projects:

- "Standalond Typescript Angular Project"
- "ASP.NET Core Web API"

and made them both startup projects (with the Web APU starting first).
This is the scenario that I actually want to use.

In this case I get exactly the same effect, but the single "Standalond Typescript Angular Project" seems to be the easiest way to reproduce the problem.

Why is Visual Studio hanging up in the deployment step?

**EDIT**

I have made another test, exactly following the instructions on the following page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022

The behavior is identical, Visual Studio hangs up waiting for the deployment to be completed.

**EDIT**

According to Microsoft, this issue is fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-blocks-waiting-for-de/10097068

Comment: This is a good description of what is happening in my solution too.  My error I get is, "An exception happened at deploy, the port 4200 configured on launch.json is unavailable."  I guess I'll try the update.  I'm running v17.4 right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the exact problem. The fix for me was to install a different Node version.

Using the **nvm** version manager for Node I was able to install the latest using:

```
nvm install lts
```

In my case, it installed v16.16.0. Then I set as current using:

```
nvm use v16.16.0
```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked perfectly. I already had the nvm version manager installed. Previously I was using version 18.6.0. Now I am using 16.16.0 and everything works.

Comment: Are you referring to nvm for windows? This? https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: I just installed VS2022 (17.4.4) and node lts (18.14.0) as of today and I get this issue starting a default angular project.

Comment: Confirmed this fix with VS 2022 and the angular + core preview template.  Installing node 16.20 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same behavior in Visual Studio 2022. In my solution are two Angular and two API-Projects. I wanted to start them both but one got stuck like you mentioned.

The reason in my case was, that for the second angular project I changed the port. I found out, when you change the standard in ng serve to something different than 4200 it will not recognize that the server is up and running. It seems to me he is checking exactly this port.

Ok, you write you use 4200. In my case in the multi startup the angular apps are first. That's different.